# Determine distance between two layers in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, measurement

I have a Photoshop document with several small layers replicated in a vertical stack, each a fixed distance apart. I want to add another copy to the bottom of the stack, the same distance as the other ones, but I want it to be exact, not just eyeballed.

Is there a way I can determine the distance between two layers so I can place the new one the same distance below the last one?

Comment: Depending on the situation, I'd probably draw a guide rectangle between your first 2 layers, then copy that rectangle along with the second layer and move them both down while holding shift until they snap at the same position. Then repeat as many times as needed. When you are done, assuming that you gave rather unique name for the guide rectangle, you can search for them by name and easily hide all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do similar to what Joonas said in comment.

Guide to bottom edge of one object (obj 1), guide to top and bottom of the next object (obj 2).

Draw a rectangular marquee from bottom edge of obj 1 to the top edge of obj 2 then drag the marquee so the top of the marquee is at the bottom edge of obj 2. Drag a guide down. Repeat.

Might need to switch layers as you go so that it snaps to the right object.

Comment: Same here, I use slices, just because I find it easier to measure and modify them (double click).

Answer (score 1):

- Zoom in until you see the Pixel Grid.
- Choose Window > Measurement Log to open the Measurement Panel
- Make certain View > Snap is checked and View > Snap To > Layer is checked
- Grab the Ruler Tool (click and hold the Eyedropper Tool)
- Click on the outer pixel f one layer and drag to the other layer. The preview line should snap to the pixels.
- Click Record Measurement on the Measurement Panel. The Panel will then display the distance under the Length column.

Comment: Why not just select all the layers and use distribute evenly?

Comment: @Ryan - Ever tried to distribute evenly with text objects? Or uneven objects? There is no "distribute spacing" option in Photoshop (believe it or not) Photoshop's distribute buttons only really work well when all the objects being distributed are the same dimensions.

Comment: Ah I guess I did make an assumption about what was being distributed when really I have no idea if the shapes are the same or not.